# Android - JNA library

Tags: android, jna

Hello i'm using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to be able to use an external .dll(i don't have the header file but i have documentation thus the exposed function signatures).

I have managed to use my dll in a java project following [the instructions here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) and now i'm trying to use the same thing on an android app.

I imporetd the jna jar in my libs and also added the jar in my buildpath and i'm getting an error

```
The library 'jna-3.5.1.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
The following libraries were found:
com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
com/sun/jna/linux-i386/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the libraries you don't need by repacking or rebuilding `jna.jar`.  JNA bundles a bunch of native libs for convenience on desktop systems; you don't need them on a [mobile deployment](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md).

Comment: @technomage I did that and i cannot instantiate any class or interface now..

Comment: Edit your question to represent what you've tried and the results you've encountered.

Comment: I got error the same like your question  when i use  'tincan-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-jarjar.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This deserves an answer...

Did you compile the lib you wanna use for android?

Why not write a JNI wrapper around those native libs, and invoke that from your android app?

Comment: How can i compile the lib?I'm using JNA for ease of use as i read in articles before starting the whole process.Nevertheless if you can suggest a good tutorial on how i can achieve it with JNI i can change the implementation.

Comment: You don't need to compile the android version of the JNA native library, it's available in the JNA project under `lib/native/android-arm.jar`.

Comment: @Shark Am i suppose to import this jar only or what?Cause i imported and the classes i need are not there.

Comment: `android-arm.jar` contains the shared library you need to include in your android project like you would any other shared library.  You *do not* include `android-arm.jar` directly.  `jna.jar` (minus the other shared libraries) contains all the Java classes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Browse your jna.jar and delete the files displayed on your message :

```
com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
com/sun/jna/linux-i386/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
```

Then maybe you need to restart your IDE and that should work.