# JNA for android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jna

1. I have a huge set of C source files that when compiled result in a shared library.
2. There is also a Java version that uses JNA to access the already built c shared library. These files are available in another jar. This jar depends on jna.

First I compiled the c files and then compiled the java code. In java, there are no errors. The problem arrises only when I try to port it to android. I could easily compile the c files using the android 'ndk-build' tool. This successfully creates the shared library.

I am not able to import JNA in an Android Project because of something similar to this: [Android - JNA library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765212/android-jna-library)

However I don't understand the comments in that post. Is it possible to use JNA in Android?

I tried removing a few files from the jna.jar (the files corresponding to other architectures). Yet, I get the same error that says: 
The library 'jna.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
Including: "com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so"

The jar (the one with the java wrapper for the C library), gets imported and I can write code.
But, I still get 'ExceptionInInitializerError' with the first object I create using the classes in this jar.

I am not well versed in java. I only have the knowledge of a rookie. Please bear with me and help out. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to do your builds?

Comment: @user3228292 if the proposed answer works, don't forget to accept it

Comment: I will try this out and get back asap.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

> - Add Android SDK/NDK tools into PATH (used by native/Makefile).
> - Set environment variable NDK_PLATFORM (used by native/Makefile).
> - Build using: ant -Dos.prefix=android-arm dist.
> - Tests must be run on the target platform, not the build platform.
> - Add dist/jna.jar and/or dist/platform.jar to your application, as needed.
> - If you're using android-maven-plugin, jna.jar can be used as-is (native libraries will be automatically copied into your project).
> - If you're using Google's Eclipse plugin then you must manually remove libjnidispatch.so from jna.jar/lib/armeabi and add it into your project's libs/armeabi directory.
> - See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17861 and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html for more information.

Copied from https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md:

Comment: Please clarify the following, 
1. build using: ant -Dos.prefix.... bhuild what using this?
2. Tests must be run on the target and not build platform - please elucidate, I don't understand. The target and build platforms are both Android, right? Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: As described i only copied the description, try to contact the JNA guys directly

Comment: It didn't work. I didn't have to build JNA since the version for android-arm is already available for download as a jar.